# Formatting Comments in Review

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2013, review

In MS Word 2013, in "Review": typing in the 'New Comment'window in the right margin, the default seems to be double space -- even using the line-spacing tool won't change the typed comments to single space. I'm marking essays with multiple comments that must all appear on a print-out without being collapsed. How can I format my comments to single space?

Answer (score 0):

*I don't think that MS-Word rejects the Format for the Comments.*

To Format the Comment you have two simple options.

1. Select the Comment and Right Click, at the top of the Menu you find Command 
   Icons to Format the Comment text and they are as simple as we Format the 
   usual Text in the file.

   Or

   Simply select the Comment Text and from Home Tab you can select any of the 
   Format commands. Size, Colour, Alignments I can say every thing.
2. Other is Style. You can apply any of the ready to use Styles or Created New 
   Style.

**Hope this help you.**

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I've tried everything you suggested, and most everything works: font, bold, italic, underlining colour, highlighting. HOWEVER, neither style (no spacing) or the line & paragraphing spacing tool will change the double spacing. Any different ideas?

Comment: @DavidM. I got the perfect Solution for you. Comment doesn't accepts few of the Formatting features as you have described.  So to get rid from all these, select the Comment, Right Click, hit Style, and Create your own Style. This accepts everything including Line & Paragraph Space, Number, Bullets, Indents,,.

Answer (score 0):

As a kind of workaround, you can print just the comments, separately.

If you have other tracked changes in the documents (text additions and deletions, etc.), first hide them. On the **Review** tab, in the **Tracking** group, click **Show Markup**, and then clear the check marks nexts to **Ink**, **Insertions and Deletions**, and **Formatting**, leaving only **Comments** selected.

Then click **File** > **Print**, and under **Settings**, select the drop-down arrow for the first setting (it may currently be set to **Print All Pages: The whole thing**), and select **List of Markup: Your tracked changes**. Adjust other settings as you require, and then click **Print**. The full comments (uncollapsed) will be printed.

If you also need to print the full document showing your additions and deletions, etc., you can then do that. Add the check marks that you cleared, and then reselect **Print All Pages: The whole thing** (or whatever your default printer setting is) to print the whole document plus markup.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply -- greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: @DavidM. Pls read https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers